# How to Append Bytes to ByteArray in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, byte

I am a beginner in Kotlin and I was trying to append bytes at the end of a `ByteArray`. How can I do that ?

Here is one way I tried. Does it look right?

```
var someByteArray = byteArrayOf(*payload, 0x01.toByte())
```

where `payload` is a `ByteArray`

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`ByteArray` overloads the `plus` operator, so you can just add to the previous value directly, or assign to a new array. For example:

```
val startArray = byteArrayOf(0x1, 0x2, 0x3)
val newArray = startArray + 0x4.toByte()
```

Or if you want to keep the mutable `var`, you can just plus-assign it:

```
var array = byteArrayOf(0x1, 0x2, 0x3)
array += 0x4.toByte()
```

Comment: Is it alright to use this if I want to add multiple, say 6 items, in this manner, in terms of performance? I mean, in C#, if it were a string, concatenating string in this way results in multiple new strings, so C# has a specialised class like StringBuilder for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah not very performance friendly. If you're doing a lot of manipulations I would recommend precalculating the size of the array if at all possible, and then copying into the correct indices.

Comment: i use the + operator on 2 bytes i want to join into a byteArray and the resultant variable becomes an Integer. This is unexpected